# localize strftime rails 2.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

```
<%  @recently_active_objects = Activity.find(:all, :limit => 10, :order => "id DESC")  %>

<% @recently_active_objects.group_by{ |object| object.created_at.midnight }.each do |day, objects| %>
<h3><%=  day.strftime("%A, %B %e")  %></h3>

                <% objects.each do |object| %>
                <%= activity_message_for_activity(object) %>
                <% end %>

<% end %>
```

How do you localize `day.strftime` in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `day` is a `Time` instance, replace `strftime` by `l`.

```
<% @recently_active_objects.group_by{ |object| object.created_at.midnight }.each do |day, objects| %>
  <h3><%=l day, :format => :weekmonth %></h3>
  <% objects.each do |object| %>
    <%= activity_message_for_activity(object) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Then go to your `en.yml` file and add the following item.

```
en:
  time: 
    formats: 
      weekmonth: "%A, %B %e"
```

Add the `weekmonth` definition to every language file.

Comment: uh you still have strftime in your example. Is this intentional?

Comment: It's hard to figure out the error without the stack trace. Try to use a standard value for :format instead of :weekmonth. If it works, you might have some problem in your en.yml file.